# Loading Keras model, weights, and character index into other python application

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I've trained a Keras LSTM classification model on characters, saved its model architecture and weights, and now want to load it into a separate application that I can run separate from the training system, stick a REST endpoint on it, and then be able to make predictions via REST...

I haven't found - maybe poor googlefu - references to how other people are doing it, and the main vagueness I'm running into is how to load the original text index & the corresponding labels index.

i.e. the index of `1="a",2="g",3=" ",4="b"`, and the "original" labels of `["green","blue","red","orange"]` prior to the label being 1-hot encoded...

So this is my understanding:

- the weights are based on the numerical inputs that were given to the originally trained model
- the numerical inputs & the generated index are based on the specific data set that was used for training
- the outputs from the model that represent the classification are based on the order in which the original data set's labels were added - i.e. if `green` was in position 0 of the training labels, and is in position 1 of the actual "runtime" labels, then that's not gonna work... true?

which means that reusing the model + weights, not only requires the actual model architecture & weights, but it also requires the indices of the input & output data...

Is that correct? Or am I missing something major?

Because the thing then is... IF this is the case, is there a way to save & load the indices other than doing it manually?
Because if it needs to be done manually, then we kinda lose the benefits of keras' preprocessing functionality (like the `Tokenizer` and the `np_utils.to_categorically`) that we WERE able to use in the training system...

Does anybody have a pattern for doing this sort of activity?

I'm currently doing something along the lines of:

- save the X index & the Y label array during training together with the model architecture & weights
- in the prediction application, load and recreate the model with the architecture & weights
- have a custom class to tokenise input words based on the X index, pad it to the right length, etc
- make the prediction
- take the prediction and map the highest probability item to the original Y labels array, and therefore figure out what the predicted label is